# Irreducibility of a family of univariate polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

While doing work on another problem, I came across the following family of polynomials: $$P_e(x) := ex^{2e} - x^{2e-1} - x^{2e-2} - \cdots - x + e\in \mathbb{Z}[x],$$ where $e\geq 1$ is an integer. After doing some computations in sage, it seems that the polynomials $P_e$ are irreducible; this I checked for all $e\leq 500$. On the other hand, I don't see a simple argument why this should be the case.

> **Question:** Are the polynomials $P_e$ always irreducible for $e\geq 1$?

Of course one natural thing to try is to find a prime number $q$ such that $P_e$ is irreducible mod $q$. There is no guarantee this would work, since there could be $P_e$ that are irreducible, yet reducible modulo every prime $q$. And indeed, this appears to be the case with $P_{12}$ (and some others); at least sage tells me $P_{12}$ is reducible modulo every prime $q<60000$.

I also see that the polynomials $P_e$ are self-reciprocal. Perhaps this added structure could be useful in checking for irreducibility, though I'm not sure how.

Any suggestions or insights are welcome, as this is really not my area.

Comment: Although $P_{12}$ is reducible modulo many (and likely all) primes, its reducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be ruled out by considering it modulo $11$ and modulo $23$: The first one shows that if it is reducible, the factors must be of degree $4$ and $20$; the second one puts the degrees as $8$ and $16$.